# Provision resources to deploy React(MERN)/Angular(MEAN) app via AWS CloudFormation

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, react-redux, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I was looking at available templates to provision the necessary resources to deploy a React(MERN)/Angular(MEAN) application using Cloud Formation.

[AWS Sample templates doesnot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-sample-templates.html) have any reference or pointers to achieve the same. Any pointers to the template to play around with would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a React / Angular app, you get a bunch of HTML, CSS & JavaScript files. Simply upload these to an S3 bucket, enable [static website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) on it & your app would be live! CloudFormation would be overkill here. Even if you do use it, the only resource in the template will be an S3 bucket with static website hosting enabled. For a detailed screenshot-guided step-by-step tutorial on how to create, build & deploy an Angular app on S3, please see [my blog post](https://harishkm.in/2020/06/15/create-build-deploy-angular-spa-on-s3/).